pandas- merge to datasets with diff col names adding values from the second into the first
I have a couple of dataframes:
DTime               A B C
2023-02-21 00:00:01 0 0 0 
2023-02-21 00:00:02 0 1 0 
2023-02-21 00:00:03 0 0 2 
2023-02-21 00:00:04 4 2 0 


DTime             AAA BBB CC DDD EE
2023-02-21 00:00:01 0 0 0 1 0
2023-02-21 00:00:02 0 1 0 0 0
2023-02-21 00:00:03 0 0 2 0 1
2023-02-21 00:00:04 1 0 0 0 0

I need to merge the first into the second where I explicitly map the cols and sum the values. i.e. - I want A to sum into AAA, B into BBB and C into CCC:
DTime            AAA BBB CC DDD EE
2023-02-21 00:00:01 0 0 0 1 0
2023-02-21 00:00:02 0 2 0 0 0
2023-02-21 00:00:03 0 0 4 0 1
2023-02-21 00:00:04 5 2 0 0 0

I can't seem to make this happen without going line-by-line... But there must be a better way since I have thousands of rows and hundreds of cols.

Do you have a map of column names, like {'A': 'AAA',...} or is it just by the order of the columns?

I do have a list of the col names I want to merge for each iteration through a process... so I can create that map: {'A':'AAA'} ...

Although I say I want to do all the merging in 'one swoop' in the question above, I really have to do it in waves... like just {'A':'AAA'} ... then later, when I figure out another mapping, I'll do ('B':'BBB'}, etc... I don't know all the mappings a-priori so I will have to do some looping, computation, merging...

Code
m = {'A': 'AAA', 'B': 'BBB', 'C':'CC'}
out = (df2.set_index('DTime')
          .add(df1.set_index('DTime').rename(m, axis=1), fill_value=0)
          .reset_index()
)

out:
                 DTime  AAA  BBB  CC  DDD   EE
0  2023-02-21 00:00:01    0    0   0  1.0  0.0
1  2023-02-21 00:00:02    0    2   0  0.0  0.0
2  2023-02-21 00:00:03    0    0   4  0.0  1.0
3  2023-02-21 00:00:04    5    2   0  0.0  0.0


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'DTime': ['2023-02-21 00:00:01', '2023-02-21 00:00:02', '2023-02-21 00:00:03', '2023-02-21 00:00:04'], 'A': [0, 0, 0, 4], 'B': [0, 1, 0, 2], 'C': [0, 0, 2, 0]}
data2 = {'DTime': ['2023-02-21 00:00:01', '2023-02-21 00:00:02', '2023-02-21 00:00:03', '2023-02-21 00:00:04'], 'AAA': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'BBB': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'CC': [0, 0, 2, 0], 'DDD': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'EE': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


merge the columns on 'DTime', then you will be able to sum the relevant columns.
If the column names always follow the logic observed in the question example (i.e., column names in df1 are contained in the matching column names in df2), you can dynamically build a list matching_cols with tuples containing the column names that should be summed.
If that's not always the case, you may need to change the logic for creating matching_cols
out = df1.merge(df2, on="DTime")

df1_cols = df1.columns[1:]
df2_cols = df2.columns[1:]

matching_cols = [(col1, col2) for col1 in df1_cols for col2 in df2_cols if col1 in col2]

for col1, col2 in matching_cols:
    out[col2] = out[col2] + out[col1]

out.drop(columns=df1_cols, inplace=True)

                DTime  AAA  BBB  CC  DDD  EE
0 2023-02-21 00:00:01    0    0   0    1   0
1 2023-02-21 00:00:02    0    2   0    0   0
2 2023-02-21 00:00:03    0    0   4    0   1
3 2023-02-21 00:00:04    5    2   0    0   0


rename the columns to have matching names, concat the DataFrames (you can concat more than two if needed), then groupby.sum to aggregate the values:
cols = {'A': 'AAA', 'B': 'BBB', 'C': 'CC'}

out = (pd.concat([df1.rename(columns=cols), df2])
         .groupby('DTime', as_index=False)
         .sum().convert_dtypes()
       )

Output:
                 DTime  AAA  BBB  CC  DDD  EE
0  2023-02-21 00:00:01    0    0   0    1   0
1  2023-02-21 00:00:02    0    2   0    0   0
2  2023-02-21 00:00:03    0    0   4    0   1
3  2023-02-21 00:00:04    5    2   0    0   0


Thx folks... that works! Much tighter
